# iOS open with specific apps

Tags: ios, iphone, email, sms, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to show apps from UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate , default apple apps like; sms, email or UIPasteBoard (Facebook and Twitter is optional) . Just like the similar of Dropbox app :

[image]

How can I handle this kind of situation? I've done already open apps from their UTI's, open just email or just sms but I don't how to show all of them in one sheet.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking at an UIActivityController instead of a UIDocumentInteractionController, which I believe Apple is trying to phase out.

Check out the docs here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try QLPreviewController. This will give you desired result.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html